# Minimal uniquely achieved of a funcional in space Hilbert

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have the follow problem : Let be $H$ a Hilbert space and $E \subset H$ a closed space of $H$. Give a $w \in H$ such that $w \not \in E^\perp$, show that 
$$\inf_{v \in E, |v| = 1}\big<w,v\big> $$
is uniquely achieved.

I know how to show that $\inf_{v \in E, |v| = 1}\big<w,v\big> $ is achieved, but not that is uniquely achieved.

Comment: What is $M$?$\ $

Comment: [link](Sorry @JackM),, $M = E$.

Comment: any ideas for this problem?